# xamarin.forms IOS keyboard disables page in back until keyboard is hidden

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a chat application. When the user types, the softkeyboard toggles. When the user hits "send" the keyboard goes away. He then has to hit send again, for hte button click to register.

As long as the keyboard is visible, none of the buttons or anything on the page works. Click anywhere, and it hides the keyboard and everthing will work again.

How can I circument that?
(No, even the handlers to the function arent called, so I cannot disable the keyboard upon button click ...)

Comment: If I understand correctly do you want to hide the keyboard when clicking anywhere?

Comment: hello, no not really. that already happens. I wanna type in the keyboard and the click send to fire the event handler mapped to it. but as long as the keyboard is open, the even handler doesnt fire, instead, if closes the keyboard. then I can hit send, so its two clicks instead of one and my client hates it

Answer (score 0):

We could override the event when clicking on send button on keyboard.

Create a custom renderer for Entry/Editor .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{

    class MyDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldReturn(UITextField textField)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
            return false;
        }
    }
    class MyRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.Delegate = new MyDelegate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Forms

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi",(sender)=>{ 
         // do something .    
});
```

In this way the keyboard would not dismiss when clicking on send button ,and you fire the event with messaging center.

Comment: But what If the user clicks NOT on send, just anywhere to disable the keyboard? Will this still send? How do I get the intent of the user?

Comment: No , the method will only invoke when click on send button .

Comment: Ok, maybe I havnt made myself clear: I dont want thekeyboard not to dissmiss, I want it to dismis and at the same time, fire the event attached to my button "send". But as of rn, when the keyboard is open and the user hits send, it doesnt send a message but instead closes the keyboard. The user now has to hit send yet again and now the event handler to the button fires.

Comment: Ok , i understand , could you provide a basic, reproducible project to test ? You can just upload it to github and attach the link here .